# Android - Custom BigPicture style notification not working in android 13 device

Tags: android, push-notification, android-12, custom-notification

After updating the android project to android 12, **big picture style custom notifications** are not working in Android 13 devices, but they work in lower versions of Android 12 & below devices.

If I use the local image drawable it is working in Android 13 also, if I load an image from the URL in custom big picture style notifications it is not working in Android 13.

Custom text style notification is working fine in Android 13 & below devices.

please refer to the image below from Android 13, Custom Big picture expanded notifications,

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I use a smaller width image, it is displayed in a custom picture style notification in the Android 13 device without any change. If I image with higher width then this problem occurs.

I fixed it by overriding the width and height of an image using a glide when loading. For Android 12 & below version devices, the image will load without this fix.

```
Glide.with(context).asBitmap()
                .override(500, 500)
                .load(imgUrl)
                .submit().get()
```